# How do I copy differing content files from one directory to another?

Tags: linux, command-line, directory, diff, cp

There exists two directories: `a/` and `b/`.
I'd like to copy all the files(recursively) from `a/` into `b/`.
However, I only want to copy over an `a` file if its content is different than the already existing `b` file.  If the corresponding `b` file does not exist, then you would still copy over the `a` file.

*by "corresponding file", I mean a files with the same name and relative path from their parent directories.

*note:*
The reason I don't want to overwrite a `b` file with the same exact contents, is because the `b` directory is being monitored by another program, and I don't want the file date to change causing the program to do more work than required.

I'm essentially looking for a way to perform a `cp -rf a/ b/` while performing a diff check on each file.  If the file's are different, perform the copy; otherwise skip the copy.

I see that `cp` has an update flag:

```
   -u, --update
          copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination  file  or  when  the
          destination file is missing
```

but this will not work because I'm not concerned about newer files; I'm concerned about different file contents.

Any shell language will do.
I've been attempting to get this to work by injecting my diff check into a find command:

```
find a/ ??? -exec cp {} b \;
```

This doesn't seem like an uncommon thing to do between two directories, so I'm hoping there is an elegant command line solution as aposed to me having to write a python script.

Comment: If you don't care about the efficiency that much, something like `if $(diff a b) move` could work.  Sorry, I know the syntax  is wrong, bash I always forget.

Comment: Just realized you said any shell language; `if not diff a b; echo "different"; end` works for fish shell.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using **rsync**. Files or directories will be updated only if there is any new update in source folder.

```
$rsync -av --progress sourcefolder destinationfolder
```

Comment: If I update the file timestamp but not the content, it still transfers the file.  This is giving me the same effect as `cp -ruf sourcefolder destinationfolder`.

Comment: In case of cp, It will ask whether you want to overwrite the file or not. In case of rsyc It simply checks and update.

Comment: If you run with v(verbose) option. It shows how many bytes it copies. In case of timestamp change, It will show Zero byte copied.

Comment: `cp` will not ask whether you want to overwrite without `i`.  
Oh, I see the byte count now.  Maybe its not updating the file, but its still changing the timestamp despite any of the file content changing.